# Word Search Game Issue

Tags: android, andengine, tilemap

I am developing a game like word search. I have used AndEngine for this and for displayig grid of words I have used TiledMap. In this game, we need to join letters to make a word as we drag our fingure it will draw line on tiles and make connection between letters. I am able to draw lines vertically and horizontally accurately but as I try to draw line diagonally it goes to the nearby tile and draw line from last touched tile to nearby tile. But as I carefully move to the diagonal tiles it draws line accurately.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

```
e.g.
----------------
|1   2   3   4 |
|5   6   7   8 |
|9  10  11  12 |
----------------
```

as shown in above e.g.

I am able to draw line for `"1234" & "159"`, It means all horizontal and vertical positions works accurately.
But for `"963"` its not as accurate as i draw for horizontal and vertical.

[image]

I want to draw line on one board as shown above. There will be letters below lines and need to connect correct words.

Comment: can you add screen-shots?

Comment: added pic as per my requirement..

Comment: It sounds to me like when you are moving diagonally, the game is detecting a hit on an adjacent tile before you get to the diagonal tile. Maybe you could use a radius from the center of a tile to detect the hit?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot instead? Considering the existing answer, your question is not very clear. It sounds to me you are calculating wrong tile from the touch coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than detecting each tile as the touch position passes over it, you could contiually detect the direction a touch has moved from its own starting point, and lock that direction to the 8 horizontal/vertical/diagonal directions ([like this question's topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49290/whats-the-best-way-of-translating-a-2d-vector-into-the-closest-8-way-compass-di)).

I'll reference your artwork  :)

```
----------------
|1   2   3   4 |
|5   6   7   8 |
|9  10  11  12 |
----------------
```

For example, the first touch is at the center of `10`.  Assuming an origin at the top-left, that position is `(1.50, 2.50)`.  Now that touch moves toward tile `7`, and it gets a vector position of `(2.01, 2.01)`.  Purely from the current touch location, that is within tile `11`.  However, the difference of these two vector positions is

```
 (2.01,  2.01)
-(1.50,  2.50)
-------------
 (0.51, -0.49)
```

Clearly, this is a diagonal vector that is closest to the direction `(1, -1)`. Knowing that and the drag distance, your logic can behave as if the touch was firmly within tile `7`.

This method will allow you to build a finite state machine for the drag direction.  You will also be able to correct for fat-fingers being unable to drag a straight line, with accuracy improving as the drag moves farther from the origin.

Answer (score -1):

Try drawing your diagonal lines using a Paint object that has ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG set to true.
You can do this when calling the constructor or by calling the "setAntiAlias" method of an existing Paint object.

Comment: I am very new to AndEngine, Can we user paint object in AndEngine?

Comment: In AndEngine, you can use GL_LINE_SMOOTH.  Here is an example:  http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/anti-aliasing-t691.html?hilit=antialiasing#p4222

Comment: -1 Perhaps I'm reading the question differently than you, but why would drawing the line anti-aliased make it more accurate for getting touch inputs? I find this answer pretty incomplete and it sounds more like a guess.

Comment: @Byte56:  The question said that the diagonal line wasn't accurate...Since the author said that the horizontal and vertical lines are OK, I took the question to mean that diagonal lines were pixelated (chunky) and that smoothing it would improve the appearance.  Maybe the author could clarify?

Comment: This bit " but as I try to draw line diagonally it goes to the nearby tile and draw line from last touched tile to nearby tile. But as I carefully move to the diagonal tiles it draws line accurately." Leads me to believe it's not a visual thing.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I was thinking that a thick jagged line could look like it was crossing into another tile.  Thanks for the feedback