# Get rotate angle using a formula

Tags: mathematics, coordinates, trigonometry

I am developing a game that is being played on a board with the top first tile having the coordinates [0,0], the next one has [0,1], second row has [1,0]... and so on (most likely this would be a standard but im not sure...).

When an object is to move around the board, it should first rotate to a specific angle - meaning if it is moving north North -  it should point to the default angle 0, NE is 45, E is 90, and so on.

How would I get this angle based on where the object is moving, but using 1 formula?

So if an object is to move NW (up and left), on the grid that would mean the destination is [y-1, x-1] in reference to where it is now [y,x] ( [row, column] ).

I know I could use 8 statements and say if destination == [y-1, x-1] then angle = 315, but I was wondering if there is a specific formula for this? Im guessing yes but I never loved trigonometry...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49290/whats-the-best-way-of-translating-a-2d-vector-into-the-closest-8-way-compass-di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your movement vector is obtained substracting source position to target position

and the angle usually in radians is

```
  Vector2 V = Target - Source; 
  angle = Math.Atan2(V.Y, V.X)
```

Comment: This isn't really a single formula, since you'd still need to use some kind of lookup table to get the `Target` and `Source` angles.

Comment: Target and source are not angles... are cell positions.. you dont need a lookup table.. you need to know where you go ;)

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not sure why I thought it was something different.